# Toast Notification in Laravela

Tags: php, laravel-5, bootstrap-toast

I am new to Programming and I am assigned to build a renting system. I'm using laravel and i'm having a hard time making a toast notification. I have no idea how can I call a `toast(bootstrap)` notification whenever the costumer successfully submitted a form.

here is my controller wherein the data is submitted successfully on the database.

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $rentform = new BorrowerRequest;
    $rentform->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $rentform->car_id = $request->car_id;
    $rentform->borrowers_name = $request->borrowers_name;
    $rentform->email = $request->email;
    $rentform->return_date = $request->return_date;
    $rentform->contact_number = $request->contact_number;
    $rentform->request_status_id = $request->request_status_id;


    $rentform->save();
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'Your Request has been successfully submitted, please wait for a couple of hours for the approval');

    return redirect('/selections');
}
```

anyone can give me a hint on how i can make a condition where a toast notification will popup in admins account whenever a formrequest is submitted by the costumer?

Answer (score 1):

> you can use [This](https://packagist.org/packages/brian2694/laravel-toastr) package for toastr notification ,, after successfully
>   install this package you need to link those css and js cdn in your
>   master template..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">

<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    {!! Toastr::message() !!}
```

> then you can use this notification like,

```
$rentform->save();
    Toastr::success('Post Successfully Saved :)','Success');
    return redirect('/selections');
```

> and also make sure that you need to use this line in your controller

```
use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;
```

> for more details visit this link::
>
> https://packagist.org/packages/brian2694/laravel-toastr

Comment: hi. thanks Md Foysal, i already type this command in my composer "composer require brian2694/laravel-toastr" but it says 
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package brian2694/laravel-toaster.

  Did you mean this?
      brian2694/laravel-toastr
.. what do you think may cause that?

Comment: composer require brian2694/laravel-toastr     just simply use this...

Comment: you can also manualy add this add those line to your project...
than just run this comand to publish ...
 php artisan vendor:publish

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2**
just create and alert .php file for alert and on it just check for session message like this

```
    @if(session('message'))

  <div
  class="toast show bg-info fade mx-auto"
  id="static-example"
  role="alert"
  aria-live="assertive"
  aria-atomic="true"
  data-mdb-autohide="false">
  <div class="toast-header">
  <strong class="me-auto">title</strong>

    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-mdb-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body text-white">

        <p>put in ur message</p>
        </div>

</div>

    @endif
```

when u have finish with the message just go in to ur view file and include the alert.php file inside like this

```
@include('alert');
```